# ASP.NET section is missing from my IIS

Tags: iis

The ASP.NET section is missing from my IIS.. 
Can you tell me what I need to do to get the ASP.NET section there.

I had published a web forms site there and I was getting a 403 error.

[image]

Comment: How did you install IIS? Show that.

Comment: I didn't install IIS.. someone else did.. do you think it wasn't installed correctly?..

Comment: Yes, very likely.

Comment: when i loaded my application (its a asp.net website) i was getting a 403 error (something related to mime type with aspx) .. do you know if that error is caused because ASP.NET is missing?